# Who owns tokens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I hit someone with [Blim, Comedic Genius](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blim%2C%20Comedic%20Genius), should I count treasure tokens they control as unowned permanents? What if I gave them the tokens with [Forbidden Orchard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Forbidden%20Orchard)?

Comment: There is no such thing as an unowned permanent in Magic the Gathering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The token is owned by the player who created it:

> 111.2. The player who creates a token is its owner. The token enters the battlefield under that player’s control.

If you use Forbidden Orchard, the target opponent is the one who creates the token, so they are the owner.

Note that this depends on using the current oracle wording of Forbidden Orchard:

> target opponent creates a 1/1 colorless Spirit creature token

Under the older wording that's printed on older editions of the card, it instead says that you "put... into play under your opponent's control", which means you would be the one who created it. But "create" didn't exist as a keyword back then, it was added later.

> 701.6. Create
>
> > 701.6a To create one or more tokens with certain characteristics, put the specified number of tokens with the specified characteristics onto the battlefield.

Comment: So what is the answer with forbidden orchard?

Comment: @Euphorbium "target opponent creates a 1/1 colorless Spirit creature token." seems pretty clear to me who is creating it and therefore who is the owner. What is unclear?

Comment: “put a 1/1 colorless spirit token into play under target oponents controll”. It seems like I am the one doing the putting.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yeah I had actually edited my answer to say that you would be the owner/creator, because I also saw the old wording first.

Comment: @Euphorbium You are missing an important point about MtG: the effective wording of any card is the Oracle wording (that in Gatherer), not what happens to be on the printing of the card that you are using.

Comment: @Euphorbium that wording is out of date, often cards are updated with new oracle text and errata because their wording is ambiguous or because rules change that means the way card are worded needs to change to keep them working as intended. The text on gatherer is the official definitive source, the text on the card was just (with one or two exceptions) the wording on the card as of the time of printing.